# Calculating the conditional probability of discrete samples

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have two lists:

```
a = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
b = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
```

I'd like to calculate the conditional probability of a given b; for example, $p(a=1 | b=0)$.

Is there a built in function to do this? The `Probability` function seems to only work with symbolic arguments?

Comment: Where is the randomness ?

Comment: a and b are the result of many (in this case 6) random simulations. I guess I am not trying to calculate the true conditional probability, but rather estimate it through many realizations of this simulation.

Comment: Oh, so you want to select all entries of $a$ corresponding to zero entries for $b$ (here : {1,0,1}) and then evaluate the proportion of 1's (here : 2/3), right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It looks like I needed to use EmpiricalDistribution as rasher showed below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a, b, dista, aa, bb]

a = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
b = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}

dista = EmpiricalDistribution[Transpose[{a, b}]]

Probability[aa == 1 \[Conditioned] bb == 0, {aa, bb} \[Distributed] dista]

(* 2/3 *)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Following A.G.'s restating of your problem you could also do this:

```
Mean @ Pick[a, b, 0]
```

> ```
> 2/3
> ```

Rather more clean, is it not? :-)

Comment: I think you need something like `Count[#, 1]/Length[#] &@Pick[a, b, 0]` for Version7:)  -- +1

Comment: @kguler `Mean` works in version 7, and I think it is equivalent to you code for binary (zero or one) lists; am I missing something?

Comment: I meant for general (non-binary) lists ... and also for other conditional probabilites (e.g Prob(a==0 given b==0)) for binary lists.

Comment: @kguler Good point.  I would still try to use use numeric methods, e.g. `1 - Mean @ . . .`.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 for being a wise-guy, I'm sure I don't have to tell you that clean it may be, but having to create a distinct numeric method for each possible probability query (much less extending them to non-binary data) would make for a bit of a mess ;-)

Comment: @rasher I'll take it. :^)  I don't have those fancy probability tools in V7 so I have to make do; in this case I rather like the result.

Comment: Looks very clean, but I have no idea how to interpret the code! thanks though!

Comment: @kamula Semantically this is quite simple; `Pick` returns every part of `a` that is at the same position as there is a `0` in `b`.  If you mean how to apply this generally to the entire class of problems rasher is right: you'd have to find a numeric equivalent every time; it's not automatic.   In any case you're welcome.